# How to improve the performance for operations on a big static array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I have a big and complicated static multidimensional array in PHP:

```
static $data = array (
 'entry1' => array(
'field1' => array(
),
'field2' => array(
)
....
)
...

);
```

The length of `var_export($data, true)` is about 2MB.

If I just want to access `$array['entry1']['field1']`, the first time it takes like ~5 second. I guess the entire array needs to be loaded in memory. Is there any advice how to improve the performance? Should I split this array into smaller arrays?

Comment: Do you have to load the entire array? Maybe using a relational DB to store the data could be a faster approach, if applicable.

Comment: Where are you getting this array? From DB? From separate php file? From csv file? 2 mb(even clean data, without overhead of var_export) is not so much.